# Twitter accounts with Facebook fan pages

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-pages, synchronization

I have number of fan pages on my Facebook account.   I am trying to get a Twitter account for each page, but because I already have my own Twitter account it will not let me connect the fan page unless I disconnect the main twitter account from my private Facebook profile.   Is there any other way to fix this?